# adding Javascript and Css to Wordpress page

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I've written a javacript and html/css for an element for my main page. I already tried putting my js file into root and "including" it in my header.
I've used gutenberg to design my page and i want to add this element to it.
can any body help me?
its bunch of js and jquery codes and css for style and flexbox html.
I have .js .css and .html files on my pc and my site is on localhost.
my themes is Astra free version.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be for you to:

1. Create an Astra child theme and Activate it as your theme. You can use their tool https://wpastra.com/child-theme-generator/

You do this to be able to continue updating Astra and not loose your custom work

2. In the functions.php file of your child theme, you use use a WordPress action hook to enqueue your CSS and your JS file, like this:

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'amir_astra_scripts' );

```
function amir_astra_scripts(){
  
  wp_register_style( 
    'amir-styles', // Idendtifier to later enqueue it
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'path/to/file/your-css.css', //full URL to the file
    true, 
    filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . 'path/to/file/your-css.css' ), // A dynamic version to bust caching
    'all'
    );  
  
  
  wp_enqueue_style('amir-styles');


  wp_register_script(
    'amir-script', 
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'path/to/file/your-js.js', 
    ['jquery'], // Make script a dependency of jquery
    filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . 'path/to/file/your-js.js'), 
    true // Load in footer instead of header
);

  wp_enqueue_script('amir-script');
  
}
```

3. If you don't need to load your CSS and JS on every single page of the site, use [WordPress conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to load them conditionally, only on the needed pages. For example, if you needed to load your CSS and JS on all blog posts, you can encapsulate the enqueuing in is_single() like this after registering them

```
if( is_single() ){
  wp_enqueue_style('amir-styles');
  wp_enqueue_script('amir-script');
}
```

If you needed them only on the page with slug "contact" you would do

```
if( is_page('contact') ){
  wp_enqueue_style('amir-styles');
  wp_enqueue_script('amir-script');
}
```